# Do all permitted range / primes combinations exist infinitely?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Leading to the question:

A prime range must be even.

In a a range between $2$ numbers, there can be only $2$ possible consecutive primes.

In the range between $4$ numbers, there are only $3,5,7$ that are $3$ consecutive primes, but other than that there could be only a max combination of $2$ consecutive primes.

In the range between $6$ numbers, there can be only a max combination  of $3$ consecutive primes.

In the range between $8$ numbers, there can be only a max combination  of $3$ consecutive possible primes.

...

**Data out of the first million primes shows that:**

So far all these possible combinations of consecutive primes within a range seem to be distributed evenly throughout infinity (twin primes, cousin primes, sexy primes, twin primes followed by cousin primes, cousin primes followed by twin primes...)

When mentioning “distributed evenly”, I mean that there is more or less a way (range) to predict the “next” occurrence.

I was trying to find ranges in which the combinations are not distributed evenly and the first small case I found is the following:

In the case of the range of $16$, whether there could be a combination of 6 primes is definitely permitted, but out of the first million primes doesn't seem to be distributed evenly:

Out of the first million primes there were only $6$ cases. the first $5$  $ \leqslant 43793$ and the last one much much further at $1091273$ not seen again (the millionth prime is $1299709$. and from there on I have no idea ...)

Here are all the $6$ cases: $7-23 , 97-113 , 16057 - 16073 , 16057 - 16073 , 19417 - 19433 , 43793 - 43777 , 1091257 - 1091273$

Am I not seeing the even distribution because 1 million primes is too small of a test range?

In theory do all permitted range/primes combination go on to infinity? or is it possible to have a finite limit?

Comment: Cf. [Prime $k$-tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_k-tuple).

Comment: The midpoint has to be an odd multiple of 15; and except for the first one has to be an odd multiple of 105.  Then other primes reduce your chances by $5/11,7/13,11/17,...$

Comment: @Cf. I read it and I got the answer. Citing the article: “It is conjectured that every admissible k-tuple matches infinitely many positions in the sequence of prime numbers”  and so I guess also that as far as even distributions goes, it has to do with the limited list and that is why I can’t see it yet.

Comment: The twin prime conjecture shows that we even do not know this for the case of difference $2$, but everything speaks for infinite many solutions for every admissable tuple.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "distributed evenly" ?

Comment: @Peter when analyzing the data,  you might not know when  is the "next" Tuple, but you see that the "next" Tuple will occur in a certain predictable range, eventually leading to a more or less "even" distribution.